# 19.10 Nautilus Terminal causes failure to fetch launchpad.net

Tags: apt, updates, nautilus

So I just got into Linux (or more specifically into Ubuntu) last week.
I really like the ability to customize everything, so I got ahead and started to mod my OS a bit.
I really wanted a terminal built in my nautilus file explorer.
The only option that really worked was from launchpad. 
Only each time I try `sudo apt update` I get this error message:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/flozz/flozz/ubuntu/dists/eoan/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/flozz/nautilus-terminal/ubuntu/dists/eoan/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to add a [trusted=yes] in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` files belonging to the packages which cause the problem.

I tried uninstalling the nautilus terminal, and reinstalled it according to the instructions on git-hub but it did not resolve the issue.

What shall I do?

Comment: This PPA has nothing for `eoan`.

Comment: http://ppa.launchpad.net/flozz/nautilus-terminal/ubuntu/dists/ shows the developer's last version of Nautilus Terminal was for 'Disco', i.e., 19.04. They have not yet developed a version of 19.10.

Comment: @Pilot6 well the erros dont show up anymore, but doesn't that mean that I wont get Updates for the packages any more?

Comment: @K7AAY So i have to live with it as it is for now and wait for them to Update the package?

Comment: Yep, They're dancing as fast as they can... as per https://github.com/flozz/nautilus-terminal/issues/36  Maybe there's another add-on for Nautilus, or maybe a simular file manager app has a terminal option.

Comment: @K7AAY well, thank you for clearing that up for me :D I searched a bit when first installing the terminal and there didn't seem to be a real alternative for nautilus. In addition I don't really fancy installing another file explorer for now, but may be in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/get-terminal-embedded-in-nautilus-file.html says

"You can download the DEB packages directly from the PPA source, and install them on Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan Ermine (you can download the packages from the PPA for Ubuntu 18.04 or 19.04 too, in case you don't want to add the PPA). You need to download and install the following packages from this PPA:

nautilus-terminal and python-nautilus-terminal (don't install python3-nautilus-terminal)."

That same web page also illustrates an alternate Python-based method to install it. That requires *pip* , *python-psutil*, and the *Nautilus Python bindings*, which can be installed by

```
sudo apt install python-pip python-nautilus python-psutil
```

Run [pip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/pip.1.html) to install (or upgrade from an older version) the Nautilus Terminal extension for your user, then restart Nautilus, with

```
python2 -m pip install --user --upgrade nautilus_terminal && nautilus -q
```

dconf-editor can be installed to customize how you invoke the terminal

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then you may change Nautilus Terminal settings by opening the Dconf Editor and navigating to **org > flozz > nautilus-terminal**.

Comment: Thanks, that worked and fixed all the issues!